# Xamarin.Forms Hot Reload not working in UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, hot-reload

I've read and followed all the hints for Hot Reloading in UWP on this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting?view=vs-2019

Just can't get it to work. It works in Android not iOS (which is not supported at the moment).

Any additional thought to the page mentioned above?

Comment: use this [3rd party reloader](https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/HotReload), for UWP you have to use remote debugging to get reloader working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use HotReload feature in Xamarin.Forms UWP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57503746/how-to-use-hotreload-feature-in-xamarin-forms-uwp-project)

Answer (score 4):

Recently Hot Reload "2.0" was shipped in Visual Studio 2019 16.8, which finally includes Hot Reload support for UWP. But it *only* works if you go into the Visual Studio settings and set it Changes Only (Preview), as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Visual Studio Settings - Hot Reload]

See this post for more details:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/dotnetconf-2020-xamarin-recap/#xaml-hot-reload-2-0

Answer (score 0):

No additional installation or setup is required to use XAML Hot Reload. It's built into Visual Studio and can be enabled in the IDE settings. Once enabled, you can start using XAML Hot Reload by debugging your app on an emulator, simulator, or physical device.

On Windows, XAML Hot Reload can be enabled by checking the Enable Xamarin Hot Reload checkbox at **Tools** > **Options** > **Xamarin** > **Hot Reload**.

For more information, please visit the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload).

Comment: It’s not the answer I was looking for and everything you say I already knew but on the page you pointed me to there is a remark that Hot Reload currently is not supported for Xamaring.Forms UWP. Hmmmm, too bad. So the answer should have been: You can’t right now.

Comment: @PaulSinnema as I already said, use the 3rd party reloader which supports UWP