# Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2012 Hot Reload Not Working

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have updated the project as per the Visual Studio prompt to Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2012.
When I deploy my Xamarin Forms app I see in the hot reload section of Vs 2019 that Hot Reload is initialising. When I make changes to the XAML and save I see  that Hot Reload in connected and appears to be sending the XAML changes. However, there are no changes applied to the running app's screen. I have tried two diffrent Emulator versions and my own Samsung S8 device running Android 9.Tried scanning S.O. for answers but none.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview
Version 16.10.0 Preview 1.0
Xamarin   16.10.000.21 (main@240d4e4)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   16.10.0.0 (remotes/origin/8affbf0abc24122abd5517b2b52f1073cb52bd7b@8affbf0ab)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.
```

Comment: You need to look at output pan section Xamarin HotReload for any important log

Comment: You could check your system requirement in the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload The screenshot show how the Hot Reload works. https://imgur.com/bl47kQE

Comment: @Paul Stanley in my case, this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65218142/4654957

Answer (score 8):

1. Make sure that **all projects use Xamarin.Forms** packages **of the 5th version**.
2. Check the **MS VS studio version**. Make sure that you have installed **the latest stable release**.
3. Make sure you have installed **latest SDK**s for **Android** and **IOS** platforms.
4. Check **XAML Hot reload settings**. It must be enabled.
5. There are two modes of reloading in settings:

   a) reload only components with changes (default)

   b) reload a page entirely

if the first does not work, try the second mode.

6. The latest MS VS version (16.11.3.0) has the button having the fire icon which forces to apply Hot reload.

- Also one important setting that can be enabled: all changes will be applied on you click Save. So hot reload will applied only after you save the xaml (ctrl+s)

7. Open Visual Studio **Output** window, choose **Xamarin Hot Reload** from the dropdown list, check whether a reload is started and whether changes are sent to your app using the appeared logs.

How to locate settings: *MS Visual Studio Options -> Debugging-> Hot Reload.*
Watch the screenshot with setting using the link below:

[Hot Reload settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cAtR.png)

Comment: Updated the description. It must make Hot Reload working.

Comment: One more important thing to check: the xaml validation can interrupt xaml hot reloading. It has become stricter in the latest versions. Open Visual Studio Output window, choose Xamarin Hot Reload from the dropdown list, check whether a reload is started and whether changes are sent to your app using the appeared logs.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

**"Tools => Options => Xamarin => Hot Reload"**

[image]
[image]

[Click this link for more informations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/195447/hot-reload-not-working-android-or-ios.html)